# Insert data to table from form

Tags: vba, excel

I created a simple form in Excel for inserting data to the spreadsheet. I have a table in my sheet with headlines in row 2 and blank in row 3. When I enter the data form into the first empty row, it started from row 4 (fist row under the table). I want to insert data into existing table. How can I do this?

This is Add button code in my form:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

TrackingDate = UserForm1.TrackingDate.Value
INS = UserForm1.INS.Value
COY = UserForm1.COY.Value
Amount = UserForm1.Amount.Value
InvoiceDate = UserForm1.InvoiceDate.Value
InvoiceNumber = UserForm1.InvoiceNumber.Value
PolicyNumber = UserForm1.PolicyNumber.Value
Reminder = UserForm1.Reminder.Value
Cheque = UserForm1.Cheque.Value
Status = UserForm1.Status.Value

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = TrackingDate
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = INS
Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = COY
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Amount
Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = InvoiceDate
Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = InvoiceNumber
Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = PolicyNumber
Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Reminder
Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Cheque
Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Status

End Sub
```

Comment: 1 minute of google search: http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xl-update-list.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code can be written like this:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
    Dim i&: i = [A:J].Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1 'find the last empty row range("A:J") 
    With UserForm1
        Range("A" & i).Value = .TrackingDate.Value
        Range("B" & i).Value = .INS.Value
        Range("C" & i).Value = .COY.Value
        Range("D" & i).Value = .Amount.Value
        Range("E" & i).Value = .InvoiceDate.Value
        Range("F" & i).Value = .InvoiceNumber.Value
        Range("G" & i).Value = .PolicyNumber.Value
        Range("H" & i).Value = .Reminder.Value
        Range("I" & i).Value = .Cheque.Value
        Range("J" & i).Value = .Status.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thak you @Vasily. It starting now from row 3, but the table is not extending.

Comment: what do you mean under "table is not extending"? if you have a `ListObjects("SomeTable)` then you can use `resize` method for extending of it. for example `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Name Of Your Table").Resize Range("A2:J" & i)`

Comment: Great! This is what I needed. Thank you @Vasily

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` approaching an Excel "table", the first cell that registers will be the last cell of the "table" even if that cell is blank. I haven't tested it but suspect if your "table" is all values then it won't auto-extend itself if something is entered below a blank row.

You could try adding an innocuous formula like `=Row()` in the last column of your table and hiding that column - then the table should auto-extend.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, this is not working.